# How can i make a TableView background transparent?

Tags: qml, tableview

I want to display the header, columns and rows above this image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e19r.png)

i tried with backgroundVisible: false but don't work

CustomImage {
id: tableImg
source: "qrc:/Images/tabel.svg"
anchors {
bottom: btnClose.top
bottomMargin: 4
right: slider.left
rightMargin: 10
left: scancardimg.left
leftMargin: 55
top: scancardimg.top
topMargin: 116
}
}

```
    ListModel {
        id: modelCeva
        ListElement { nrCrt: "226"; joc: "fifa"; tip: "PS5"; valoare: "600"; data: "2023-04-28"; ora: "17:09:12"; }

    }

    TableView {
        id: tableView
        anchors.fill: tableImg
        backgroundVisible: false
        clip: true
        TableViewColumn { role: "nrCrt"; title: "Nr. Crt"; width: 70; }
        TableViewColumn { role: "joc"; title: "Joc"; width: 100; }
        TableViewColumn { role: "tip"; title: "Tip"; width: 100; }
        TableViewColumn { role: "valoare"; title: "Valoare"; width: 100; }
        TableViewColumn { role: "data"; title: "Data"; width: 100; }
        TableViewColumn { role: "ora"; title: "Ora"; width: 100; }

        model: modelCeva

        style: TableViewStyle {
            headerDelegate: Rectangle {
                height: textItem.implicitHeight * 1.2
                width: textItem.implicitWidth
                color: "#00000000";
                Text {
                    id: textItem
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    horizontalAlignment: styleData.textAlignment
                    anchors.leftMargin: 12
                    text: styleData.value
                    elide: Text.ElideRight
                    color: "white"
                    renderType: Text.NativeRendering
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `backgroundVisible` to `false` for `TableView` and `alternateBackgroundColor` to `"transparent"` for `TableViewStyle`.

You can hide scrollbars by `horizontalScrollBarPolicy` set to `Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff`.

###### Example:

```
TableView {      
    backgroundVisible: false
    horizontalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff
    // ...
    style: TableViewStyle {
        textColor: "white"
        alternateBackgroundColor: "transparent"
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked.. to remove the scrollbars, vertically and horizontally any ideas i want to make my custom ScrollBar, i tried with
 horizontalScrollBarPolicy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff
        verticalScrollBarPolicy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff

Comment: You need to set horizontalScrollBarPolicy to Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff. Answer updated.